# Read utfgrid with maplibre-gl

Tags: utfgrid, maplibre-gl

Is there any way to display a UTF-Grid interaction in maplibre-gl, like there is with Leaflet?

I have read through the maplibre-gl documentation, but i haven't found anything like a UTF-Grid source.

The only way I could imagine now would be to retrieve the tile coordinates with a mouse over and then decode them manually, whereby the tiles of the current view would then have to be cached in order not to have too long latencies.

Before I try that, I wanted to ask if someone has a better approach.